# How do I get traffic control for my Google Map object?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have set my Google Map object to view as a ROADMAP, but there is no traffic options like there is on the regular Google Maps. Below is the control I am trying to get. Is this possible via the map options in the API? I tried looking in the docs but there is nothing there for that (unless I am missing something).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom control as shown on [**this example**](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom) from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that shows embedding a traffic control onto the map.
http://pietervogelaar.nl/google-maps-api-v3-traffic-toggle-button/